# How to prevent sotware installation in Windows10 w/o asking machine password

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, malware, malware-removal, malware-detection

Recently I upgraded to Windows10 and my brother did some downloading of books which brought some malwares too like mystarsearch engine, AnyProtect etc...

Even after un-installing from Contol Panel it keeps on coming back and start installing by itself. Though I have installed Windows anti malware tools but nothing happened. Some time I see installation windows popups and even after saying No or Cancel, I see them in my installed software list. Its really annoying. Random popups, random browser opening, home page gets changed every time I open my Chrome or Edge.

So my doubt is, how to stop installation of new programs without asking Admin password etc?

Thanks

Jai

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: & the answer to the second question is to make him a Standard User, instead of Administrator